# How do I hide the navigate up icon based on some condition inside a fragment In Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I'm using `Navigation Component`. It contains multiple Fragments.

Let us consider 3 fragments with the following graph. `Fa` -> `Fb` ->`Fc`.

In `Fb`, based on certain logic{logic computation is available only in `Fa` and `Fb` }, I want to hide the back arrow button in the `Fb`. How do I achieve this

Answer (score -1):

You can manually define top level destination:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
/*
Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each menu should be considered as top level destinations.
*/
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(R.id.navigation_f_a, R.id.navigation_f_b, R.id.navigation_f_c)
)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

You also can set `Fb` as `startDestination` in your navigation graph, if your navigation can start from `Fb`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       app:startDestination="@id/navigation_f_b">

<!-- Destinations -->

</navigation>
```

Comment: I don't think answers the question about how to hide the up arrow dynamically.